# Error retrieving more than 20 rows in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid set up to retrieve all the rows of data put into a search form.

If the number of rows coming back is **20 or less**, there is no problem displaying the data in the grid. I don't have or want any paging set up.

However, if there are **more than 20 rows** coming back, the grid flips out with no specific error and doesn't return the data.

Below is my JS definition for the grid.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing in the definition to successfully pull back more than 20 rows?

**HTML**

```
<div id="jqGrid_container">
                <table id="fuelTicketsGrid" class="table table-condensed"></table>
                <div id="GridPager"></div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#fuelTicketsGrid').jqGrid({
                jsonReader: { root: 'tkts', repeatitems: true },
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                autowidth: true,
                rownumbers: false,
                rownumWidth: 30,
                loadonce: true,
                edit: false,
                viewRecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                emptyRecords: "No records found",
                caption: "Fuel Tickets",
                onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
                    var grid = $('#fuelTicketsGrid');
                    var imageID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'Image_ID');
                    if (imageID != "")
                        DisplayReceipt(imageID);
                },
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'FuelTkt_ID', label: 'ID', width: 20, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'Ticket_No', label: 'Ticket', width: 60, align: "right" },
                    { name: 'Customer_Name', label: 'Customer', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'Vehicle_No', label: 'Vehicle', width: 60 },
                    { name: 'Trans_Timestamp', label: 'Date', width: 100, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                    { name: 'Image_ID', label: 'Image ID', width: 150 },
                ]
            });
            $('#fuelTicketsGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem very easy. jqGrid do **always** paging of data and the value of page size specified by `rowNum` is 20 (see the value from "Default" column in the table with option on [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). So one should either include `pager` or `toppager: true` option to allow the user to change the page or to set `rowNum` option to large enough value like `rowNum: 10000`.

By the way you use wrong options of `'navGrid'`. If you don't need the pager and the navigator bar you should don't use the method. If you do use it you should specify correct value (the pager selector) for the second parameter (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)).